# Remove billing phone validation in WooCommerce checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, validation, woocommerce, checkout

I use woocommerce plugin and i want to send sms to my customer when they bought from my site.
my woocommerce checkout page show "the mobile number is not valid" and mobile input text does not show at all. how can i disable validation of phone number or delete this field and create new phone field.
thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make the billing phone field optional as follows:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'custom_billing_fields' );
function custom_billing_fields( $fields ) {
    // Only on checkout page
    if( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) {
        $fields['billing_phone']['required'] = false;
    }
    return $fields;
}

// Remove string "(optional)" from billing phone field
add_filter( 'woocommerce_form_field' , 'remove_checkout_optional_fields_label', 10, 4 );
function remove_checkout_optional_fields_label( $field, $key, $args, $value ) {
    // Only on checkout page
    if( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() && $key === 'billing_phone') {
        $optional = '&nbsp;<span class="optional">(' . esc_html__( 'optional', 'woocommerce' ) . ')</span>';
        $field = str_replace( $optional, '', $field );
    }
    return $field;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).

Comment: thank you,I insert this code in function.php but validation of phone field is not remove. i create new field for phone and disable old field but validation error is not remove again